# Is it possible to open dev tools in MJML app in preview section somehow?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, mjml

Is it possible to open dev tools in MJML app in preview section somehow?

E.g. I would like to check that padding was applied as I expect it to. I would like to be able to check it directly inside MJML editor, instead of exporting and running HTML in browser first, since I do lots of changes and hence export and run would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe MJML app > View > Toggle Developer Tools (Win + Alt + I)?

BTW: In addition to StackOverflow, a great source of MJML support is https://mjml.slack.com/ You probably would have gotten a more prompt response there than this one. (Sorry!)